# How to enable writing on Combobox when popdown

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox, ttk

I want to enable write to the combobox widget also when he popdown:

I can write here:

[I can write here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLAIm.gif)

But i can't write when the combobox popdown:

[image: i can't write here]

I want to enable writing on them **both**
how can i do that?

Comment: What is the purpose to edit the entry of combobox when the popup is shown?  Whenever you enable the popup, you actually want to select one of the items in the popup list.

Comment: windows does something very similar in the files explorer entry for path

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show combobox drop down while editing text using tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59763822/show-combobox-drop-down-while-editing-text-using-tkinter)

Comment: no, i need to keep edit the entry also when the popdown displayed

Comment: In order to make @stovfl's Combobox work on my mac I had to set the delays in the two `after` methods to at least 20 ms.  Lower than that and the focus wasn't reset to the Entry field.

Comment: @AvielZohar ***"no, i need ..."***: [Edit] your question and explain in detail why the given link does not fulfill your needs.