# How to open drop-down list of combobox when user types in text field?

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I am trying to write an event such that when user clicks in combo text field it should open the drop-down list of `combobox` matching the key-stroke.

For example, if user types 'a' in the text field, it should show drop-down list with selected text 'a'.

If user types 'cc', it should open the list and select the item matching the text, and so on. Here is a little code with missing event.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

tkwindow = tk.Tk()

lst = ['a','aa', 'aaa', 'b', 'c','cc','ccc','d']
cbox = ttk.Combobox(tkwindow, values=lst)
cbox.grid(column=0, row=0)

tkwindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59763822/show-combobox-drop-down-while-editing-text-using-tkinter

Comment: sorry, I did not get it. Is there any simple solution?

Answer (score 0):

Easier for newbie(Entry Level).

Code:

```
 import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
lst = ('a','aa', 'aaa', 'b', 'c','cc','ccc','d' )

def checkkey(event):
   if (value := event.widget.get()) =='':
       data = lst
   else:
       data = [item for item in lst if value.lower() in item.lower()]
                                    
   update(data)

def update(data):
    lb.delete(0, 'end')

    for item in data:
        lb.insert('end', item)

e = tk.Entry(root)
e.pack()
e.bind('<KeyRelease>', checkkey)

lb = tk.Listbox(root)
lb.pack()
update(lst)

root.mainloop()
```

Output user types a:

[image]

Output user types b:

[image]

Output user types c:

[image]